# sentence similarity in Apache solr

Tags: search, solr, sentence-similarity

I am using Solr to match phrases.

**Index data:**

```
id:1
keyword:"simple  text|text with simple word |simple word text"
group:group1

id:2
keyword:"complex word| words with adjectives| text with adjective"
group:group2
```

I  have indexed phrases seperated by pipeline which come under 1 group

**Query :**

```
"Document with simple text"
```

When i  search with above query , my search result should be

```
id:1
keyword:"simple  text
Group: Group1
```

because

Query contain all the words in above phrase
i.e : "simple" and "text"

**can anyone tell how  can i do it in solr?**

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean OR operator between the search terms:

```
 Document OR with OR simple OR text
```

This will not guarantee order of the hit words, but will allow partial matches.

If you use DisMax query parser, you can also specify the minimum lower bound of ratio of terms to match (say you always want at least 50% of your terms matched). Fo that use `mm` parameter: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm_MinimumShouldMatch_Parameter

Btw, the purpose of the pipe (|) notion in your `keyword` field is unclear. Is your intent to store the values in an array instead? Use `multiValued=true` setting on the field for that and store each value individually.